# How many number of non zero pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a,b$ are both palindrome numbers, and the sum of $a$ and $b$ is $A.$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, palindrome

Given any number let say $N$, how many ways this can be written as the sum of the palindrome numbers. 
For example $1443$ there are $20$ pairs of palindrome which have sum $1443$.
$(1441, 2),
(1221, 222),
(999, 444),
(989, 454),
(979, 464),
(969, 474),
(959, 484),
(949, 494),
(898, 545),
(888, 555),
(878, 565),
(868, 575),
(858, 585),
(848, 595),
(797, 646),
(787, 656),
(777, 666),
(767, 676),
(757, 686)
(747, 696)$

I tried this and able to find all possible pairs for small numbers $ N<=10^{14} $.

- list all palindromic numbers in $O(\sqrt N * log N)$.
- Iterate through the list for all 1....$\sqrt N$

  ```
      int id = lowerBound(allPanin, n / 2 + 1);

      for (int i = 0; i < id; i++) {

          int p = Collections.binarySearch(allPanin, n - allPanin.get(i));
          if (p > 0){
              System.out.println(n - allPanin.get(i) + ", " + allPanin.get(i));
              tp += 1;
          }
      }
  ```

But how to find all pairs for $N <= 10^{18}$

Comment: This is [A260254](https://oeis.org/A260254). The graph looks interesting.